# Vaadin 14 NumberField isEditting?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

Is there a way to tell if a field is being EDITED in Vaadin?  I have a feed that updates some spinners, and wish the user ability to change values and not have system update till after the changeEvent is fired.

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure about a being-edited state. But would it be sufficient for your use case to check if the field has the focus or not? From the Java API. you can know that using `addFocusListener()` and `addBlurListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might benefit from a slightly different approach. Any value change events have the property `isFromClient`, which you can use to distinguish events from the real user and value changes that occur as a result of the server-side code updating the field.

```java
        textField.addValueChangeListener(valueChangeEvent -> {
           if (!valueChangeEvent.isFromClient()) {
               // value updated from server -> do nothing
               return;
           }
           // user changed the value, this time we want to react to it
        });
```